# Gestures confused since iOS 13

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view controller A inside an navigation controller. This navigation controller is shown with a "show details (e.g. replace)" segue from its own parent, in case it matters.

Inside controller A, I had swipe left and right gesture recognisers working fine in iOS 12. Since iOS 13, they don't work any longer. Instead, the viewWillDisappear and viewWillDisapper methods of controller A are called (which just resets the controller A).

I removed the swiped gestures, and I still have this same behaviour. So I guess there are some default swipe left/right recognisers installed for me by iOS 13.

How can I get back my iOS 12 (working) behaviour, that is, my gesture cognizer methods are called ?

Comment: Hi, your problem solved? Would please help me and look at my question too if you solve this problem please ?stackoverflow.com/questions/58609831/… Thank you very much

Comment: No, I didn't solve the problem. I worked it around (re-organisation of the UI and change of the gesture).

Comment: you mean there is no way? so what is your suggestion to implement something same?

Comment: I wouldn't say there is no way, but I did not find it, and I was hurried by time, so I took another way. The problem seems to come from the fact that Apple changed the way modal controllers are shown, and added some gestures consistent with this new way. For example a swipe down will dismiss the modal controller, which is nice, but interferes with my gestures.  You can prevent this by playing with the `modalInPresentation`property, but then it seems that all swipe gestures are disabled (not only Apple's).

Comment: Thank you very very much. wish you all the best and success

Answer (score 0):

I would try to verify that the navigation properties of the viewController have remained the same as those previously configured.

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit please ? What do you mean with "navigation properties" ? In fact, nothing changed. I just recompiled with iOS 13.

Comment: Since iOS13 the 'standard' way of presenting viewControllers has changed from iOS 12 and earlier.

Comment: Agreed, but how is that related to presented controller's internal gestures not being recognized (or over-ridden by System ones), and how to prevent this ?

Comment: @mfiore Would please help me and look at my question too if you solve this problem please ?stackoverflow.com/questions/58609831/… Thank you very much